# Why am I getting build plan errors running "stack haddock" when "stack test" works?

Tags: haskell, haddock, haskell-stack

I'm creating a new Haskell project using Stack 0.1.3.1 on Windows 8. My `stack.yaml` file looks like this:

```yaml
flags: {}
packages:
- 'lazy-engine'
extra-deps: []
resolver: lts-3.4
```

When I run `stack build` or `stack test`, everything works beautifully. I can run `haddock` manually from the command line and that works, too. But when I run `stack haddock` I get output like this:

```
Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
NOTE: the haddock command is functionally equivalent to 'build --haddock'
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      base: needed (>=4.5 && <4.9), latest is 4.8.1.0, but not present in build plan
    needed for package: array-0.5.1.0

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package base in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      array: needed (-any), latest is 0.5.1.0, but couldn't resolve its dependencies
      base: needed (>=4.2 && <5), latest is 4.8.1.0, but not present in build plan
      deepseq: needed (>=1.2 && <1.5), latest is 1.4.1.2, but couldn't resolve its dependencies
      ghc-prim: needed (-any), latest is 0.4.0.0, but not present in build plan
    needed for package: containers-0.5.6.2

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      array: needed (>=0.3 && <0.6), latest is 0.5.1.0, but couldn't resolve its dependencies
      base: needed (==4.3.* || >=4.5 && <4.9), latest is 4.8.1.0, but not present in build plan
    needed for package: deepseq-1.4.1.1

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package ghc-prim in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      base: needed (>=4.7 && <5), latest is 4.8.1.0, but not present in build plan
      containers: needed (==0.5.*), latest is 0.5.6.3, but couldn't resolve its dependencies
    needed for package: lazy-engine-0.1.0.0

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in 
    C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\lazy-engine\stack.yaml
- base-4.8.1.0
- ghc-prim-0.4.0.0

You may also want to try the 'stack solver' command
```

Obviously this is nonsense—I shouldn't have to add `base` to my `extra-deps`, especially since I'm working off an LTS package set! What is going on here?

**Update:** As discussed in [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417076/925960), this seems to have been a bug in stack and should be fixed in newer versions. See https://github.com/fpco/minghc/issues/85.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A guess: you're using a GHC install that does not include documentation, or at least not as stack expects it to be discovered. Can you try with "--install-ghc --no-system-ghc"? I may have the specific flag names wrong.

Also, how is GHC installed on your system?

Comment: `--install-ghc --no-system-ghc` made it work, but I don't know why - as far as I can tell I have the docs for `base` and the other packages installed with the global GHC. I installed GHC and stack together using MinGHC 2015-08-13 64-bit. Any idea why this would cause this problem?

Comment: No, I don't know off hand what would be causing it. I'll have a look at the MinGHC release.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the MinGHC installer. In order to get more details, I'll need to ask more questions than the comment field here is amenable to. Can you open up an issue of MinGHC's Github issue tracker?

Comment: This is a pretty old thread but I ran into this same thing. The fix is to install the ghc-doc package (available in most package managers).

Comment: @mrenaud thank you! it is very difficult to conclude this from error report.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by installing the `ghc-doc` package (available in most package managers).